Why most math books don't give names for theorems?
In many rigorous math books, theorems are only labeled with numbers (in most cases, i.e., unless the names of the theorems are too famous to omit) rather than ‘number of theorem’ or ‘Mathematician’s Name’ Theorem, and this seems to be some kind of tradition in serious math books.
Is there a good reason for this? Is it because it prevents students from getting confused with the names?
I think having the name of the mathematician who discovered the theorems or its common name has some benefits:

It is easier to remember and recall: If I were told to recall Theorem 4.18, I would just go to Chapter 4 and search for that theorem, but if I were told to recall Cauchy’s Theorem 4.18, in many cases, I would remember what that theorem is.
It makes it easier to search for these theorems on the internet: When I first learned about the Fréchet derivative, I had so many questions, but it was hard to find any help by just Googling the theorem because my book didn’t mention its name. I had to try for an hour to find its name, and after I found it, I was able to immediately find similar questions to mine and what I wanted.
It make it easier to refer to in solutions. Imagine if L'Hopital's rule didn't have a name and every time you need to use it in a solution you have to write the whole statement of the theorem, this would be very annoying, right? Even If l'hopital didn't discover this theorem but it is useful to have a name for a theorem rather than numbers.


Another question is
: How can I know who discovered the theorem if most books don’t list the names? It is very interesting to read about each mathematician's life and work, I want to know who discovered the theorems that I know.

Probably because for minor results , it is impossible to know who discovered it first.

Some mathematicians had hundreds of theorems in the same subfield. How do you propose we name them? Cauchy’s very cool real analysis theorem? Cauchy’s real analysis theorem 1?

Often, the names we learn are not the first - Pythagoras, whose name is one of the first we hear associated with a theorem, is not the actual inventor 9f the theorem. So it can be misleading to attribute theorems to names. Sometimes names are misleading: Bezout's Identity is not an identity. Given a reader of an intro book in number theory is often new to "theorem/proof" writing, it seems annoying to distract the readers with this kind of historical weirdness.

A textbook will generally only refer to a theorem by name if it has a name the general mathematics community uses for it. This could be a descriptive name ("The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus") or a person's name ("Green's Theorem"). There are no hard-and-fast rules about when or how a theorem gets a name in the community - rather, the name is established over the course of mathematical publications referring to it in the same way over a long period of time.

@AspiringMat It will still be easier to search for Cauchy's theorem in real analysis on the internet than just trying to find the theorem by any other way

@pie This is a typical misconception. It is easy, for example,  to find every mathematical statement here at stackexchange immediately, just by searching the key words, instead of names of theorems. Usually the questioners are surprised how fast this is.

@DietrichBurde Google is not very effective when searching of a Latex code but if a theorem has no latex code it could be found very easily.

@pie You can use Approach Zero for searches involving math.

Another problem is that a textbook is likely to organize the material in a different way than how it arose historically.  So different aspects of one theorem in the book might have come from different authors, while each author's contribution may be spread over several theorems.

"It makes it easier to search for these theorems on the internet" Yes, only because a tiny bit of major results have name attached to them. Paul Erdos wrote over 1500 papers. Euler wrote even more (in terms of pages at least). It is much easier to refer to theorems by their identifiers, e.g. "book + theorem number". That's pretty much what every publication does. Secondly, science is not a contest of ego. At the end of the day it doesn't matter who invented/discovered what. The result itself is what matters.

For the purpose of searchability, it would be nice to have some kind of universal id scheme for theorems, to address OP's 2nd and 3rd points. It doesn't have to be a person's name, just something that can be easily searched like a doi.
Maybe the closest to this I am aware of now is the ProofWiki.
